# How can I turn a private key into a wallet?

Tags: wallet, private-key

I created a vanity public key (wallet address) and I got the corresponding private key too. Is it possible to somehow "open" that wallet and just used it as a normal bitcoin wallet? No sweeping, no transferring to other account - just send some of the money from that account to some other.

Comment: you want to add the address to your wallet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bitcoin address is not the same as a wallet.  If you have the private key for the address, you can import the key into either Bitcoin-Qt or a lightweight wallet such as MultiBit.  You will then be able to send and receive coins using this address.

To import a private key into Bitcoin-Qt, read [**this**](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_import_private_keys_v7+)

To import a private key into MultiBit, read [**this**](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/14154/how-do-import-a-paper-private-key-into-multibit)

Comment: Could you please make a bit clearer what is the difference between a wallet and an address? Thank you for answering.

Comment: @data A wallet is just a collection of bitcoin addresses.  It does not contain any coins - the coins exist only in transactions contained in the blockchain.  So you can delete a wallet with no problems as long as you have exported the private keys associated with your bitcoin addresses.  If you create a new wallet, you can regain access to your coins by importing these private keys.

Comment: So when I import my private key, my address is automatically found by the wallet software?